# REGEX Check for Character at Beginning or End of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate an entry in a form. I was using `/^\d{9}[A-Z]$/` to check for 9 digits and a single uppercase character. I was informed that the input could be a single uppercase character and 9 digits OR 9 digits and a single uppercase character, but not both a single uppercase character then 9 digits then a single uppercase character.

Basically either `A123456789` or `123456789A` is acceptable, but not `A123456789A`

What RegEx would I use to verify that there is at least one single uppercase character at either at the beginning or end, but not both... followed or preceded by 9 digits?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am using a Javascript validator for a plugin for Joomla. That javascript just does a simple format verification. Basically it reads, test value against RegEx, return false else return true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it in one regex, this should do :

```
(^\d{9}[A-Z]$)|(^[A-Z]\d{9}$)
```

Comment: @Melvins138 I see you didn't accept any answer, not even [this one that you praised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178520/if-else-form-for-zip-code-county-filter). Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: As I am new to this community, I appreciate your explanation of some of the etiquette that I was unaware of. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget the other one ;)

Comment: AHA! Gracias! Once I get enough points, I will up vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex flavour supports it, you can use a conditional:

```
^([A-Z])?\d{9}(?(1)|[A-Z])$
```

Explanation:

```
^
([A-Z])?  # optional capture group
\d{9}
(?(1)     # if capture group 1 exist
          # then there is nothing
  |       # ELSE
    [A-Z] # there is an uppercase letter
)
$
```